# Blender: How to export animation as GLTF file

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

I have made a very basic animation in Blender (2.79) and I am trying to export it as a GLTF or GLB. I have succesfully installed the [gltf exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) and am able to export both gltfs and glbs of unanimated models no problem.

As soon as I add animation and try to export however, I get the following error message

[image]

The animation is as about as simple as it could be, I'm just experimenting. Its just the default box that changes location and rotation across 3/4 keyframes.

I am new to Blender so perhaps I am missing a step but my process is as follows: Add box to the scene, add keyframes (LocRot), go to export as I would with a static object, this has the following (default) settings.

[image]

I have tried clicking `Pushdown` on the action sheet as I have seen suggested somewhere but it makes no difference.

Am I missing something? Please let me know if you need any more info in order to advise, I'm happy to share the file or whatever might help.

NB this will eventually be used in a-frame so any specific tips on export for that would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a bug in the exporter. Are you able to share the simple `.blend` file you've created? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy sure, of course, thanks for your help. Can I share files through this site?

Comment: hi @DonMcCurdy weird way of doing it but i've put it up here on glitch https://cdn.glitch.com/960bec91-a848-49b3-9fbd-7eaccc76edf4%2Fanimationtest.blend?1544204397942 let me know if you can get that ok

Comment: Glad you got it working! This file also seems to export OK without the `Force Sample Animations` setting in the newer exporter, https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.

Answer (score 9):

So after seeing someone else's export settings (thanks to the a-frame slack channel) I have got this working. I needed to have `force sample animations` selected in the animation export settings. Then it exports no problem and works as expected. Answering my own question in case anyone else has this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain how to do it because I can't find the ```force sample animations```

Answer (score 0):

To export multiple animated objects with armatures, vertex groups should have unique names. Here's a little script to rename bones and vertex groups based on parent armature name:

```py
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == "ARMATURE":
        prefix = obj.name + "_"
        for bone in obj.data.bones:
            bone.name = prefix + bone.name
        
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        prefix = obj.parent.name + "_"
        for vg in obj.vertex_groups:
            if vg.name[0:len(prefix)] != prefix:
                vg.name = prefix + vg.name
```